# BigQuery View Metadata - get count

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, view, metadata

When selecting metadata from BigQuery tables, for example via

```
SELECT * FROM <set>.__TABLES__;
```

It will return metadata including the row count. Views returned in the same way do not provide a row count.

Is there any similar means by which the number of records in a View can be seen, perhaps via some metadata collected by a different query?

Comment: You can execute a query as DRYRUN, that will return the number of bytes processed. I know this is not the answer you are looking but may help in some situation.

Comment: Is there any inconvenient with `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM <YOUR_VIEW>`?